# Dashed and Solid Line Signs on a Battery

Tags: charger, batteries

What is the meaning of the solid and dashed line on a battery or charger? I will give two examples below and the first one is a 4-cell battery and it says "7.6V [dotted/dashed line] 54.4 Whr 7150 mAh". How can I calculate one cell's capacity? And what is Li-Ion Polymer? Isn't it Li-Ion or Li-Poly? How can be possible that using two different battery types on a single battery?

And the second one is a charger and it says "Output: 19V [dotted/dashed line] 3.42A"

Sorry for the qualities of the pictures but these are the best ones that I could found.

[image: First one-battery]

[image: Second one-charger]

Comment: *Universal* symbol for DC. Dashed line is ground, solid line is the battery voltage.

Comment: @Mattman944 Comparing to the AC symbol, I would say the solid one is the ground

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means "DC" (Direct Current). As opposed to "AC" (Alternating current).

[image]